# Example Code for a SQL trigger to Generate an MQTT Message

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am a project manager (Thus not an experienced developer) designing an interface solution between 2 enterprise applications.
I need to write an outline design document to describe the interface between a process control system and a database. I want to provide some sample SQL Trigger code to help me explain the process.
Please can someone point me to some SQL Trigger code that could generate an MQTT message? 
The sample code should trigger on an Insert or Update and then generate an MQTT message containing some fields from the affected row. It does not need to wait for an acknowledgement.
The SQL server will be running on Windows, and the MQTT broker on Linux. I will use Nodered to receive the MQTT message, apply a little business logic and then generate an OPC-UA message for a process control system to receive. It would also be good if the MQTT message could contain a flag that indicates if the trigger was an update or an insert.
I am assuming I will need to install an MQTT cient on the SQL server such as MQTT.FX (https://mqttfx.jensd.de/index.php)

Comment: It’s always a hassle to do work in a Trigger, especially if you want to interfere with com or clr. MaBe it’s easier from a transaction standpoint to fill a journal table and have it beeing polled in small batches by a external service which feeds your queues?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing almost the same thing as you with process control data from remote terminal units and electronic flow computers, except I am buffering the trigger data into SQL service broker queues and then off to the IOT world.

You can use a .Net MQTT client right inside SQL Server but I would not recommend it as SQL Server will unload the assembly whenever it feels like it and will orphan all the sockets and they will be in limbo until the server is restarted.

The way around this is to create a Windows Service that hosts a WCF Service that contains an instance of a MQTT client and expose WCF methods to publish or subscribe (try using MQTTNet - https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet).

Once your WCF server is complete you will need to create a SQL CLR Assembly (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Calling-WCF-Service-from-a-8071ceaa) to call the WCF service, don't forget that in SQL 2017 on you will need to have the assembly strong named to install correctly.